# Error Message:  "Resource ExperimentFrame.res not found"

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-2007

I'm trying to create a frame VCL inside my project using factory pattern

something like this:

```
TFrame* newToolbarFrame =
   FrameFactory::getInstance().createObject(toolbarFrameClassId);
```

When the factory creates the implementation class, I get an error message about missing resource file.

For example if I create an instance of class `TFrameFooBar`  using factory, I get this  Exception:

> Project gymAce raised  EResNotFound with message "Resource TFrameFooBar not found" .

This looks bit like an IDE issue.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFrame is trying to perform DFM streaming of its design-time properties, but your app is not linking in the actual TFrameFooBar class's DFM into the executable's resources for TFrame to find at runtime.